ADC(MC3208) Interface Circuit Design
I am currently designing a Multi-ADC PCB for use different sensors, I've researched a range of different sources and would like some clarification on a few things before I finalise my design.
I am using the MCP3208 ADC Link to datasheet, with a 4.096 reference (MCP1541). Vdd will be the 5V supply from an Arduino Mega, connected via SPI.
I am planning on connecting the following Pressure Sensors Link to datasheet to it:
These will be powered from a separate 5V power supply, which will be connected to the Analogue plane of the circuit
I have a few questions about the implementation:

I'm aiming to have a sample rate of around 1KHz (twice the device frequency), as the datasheet states the response time of the sensor is ≤2ms (500Hz). Should I also include a Anti-Aliasing filter to interface this sensor to my ADC or is this not required? If so would a simple RC filter suffice or something more complex like a Sallen-Key Butterworth filter be required? and how should I select the cut-off Frequency?

I am slightly confused about the use of different ground planes, Section 6.5 of MCP3208's datasheet says that the device should have both AGND and DGND connected to the Analogue Ground plane. Will this cause any issues with SPI? do I need to also ensure that the Arduino Ground is connected to the AGND on the circuit so that SPI works?

I have included some 100nF Bypass capacitors at Vdd of the ADC  connected to AGND to help reduce noise. Is this correct? Is there any additional capacitors I should place on the board?


